# php connect postgres sql error can you help me?

Tags: php, postgresql

i setup bitnami postgressql and php

phpinfo loads without problem, but
The postgres part of phpinfo is fine
However, if you try to access the database, an error occurs.

```
<?php
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
try {$conn=@pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=Test user=postgres password=1234");
} 
Catch (Exception $e) {
    Echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

```
pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: ġ������: "Test" �����ͺ��̽� ����
```

I was using postgres sql 10,12 and the latest version of php Apache,

but I couldn't connect each, so I deleted all the existing ones and installed bitnami's postgres version 11.4, which was guaranteed to connect, and then reinstalled pgadmin4.
It doesn't seem to be linked to 11.4.

I don't know if it is because of that, but when I try to find the table in pgadmin it keeps giving me an error saying there is no relationship

i am looking for a solution to these.

Can you tell me how to install postgres -php -aphachi correctly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it was ' ' error
ZWSP error

������: "Test" �����ͺ��̽� ����
is ZWSP haha